# PHP ob_* from cronjob?

Tags: php, cron

I'm experiencing some problems with `ob_*` function when it runs as a cronjob:

```
<?php
function getLayout($file, $extract=array()) {

    if (is_file($file)) {

        if (count($extract) > 0) {
            extract($extract);
        }

        ob_start();
        include $file;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $contents;
    }

    return false;
}

file_put_contents('somecachefile.html', getLayout('somefile.php', array('var1'=>$val1, 'var2'=>$val2)));
?>
```

The cronjob is setup like this: (runs every minute)

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/cron.php > /dev/null
```

In this case nothing happen but the cron really ran.

If I call this (`/usr/bin/php /path/to/cron.php`) from the command line everything is working as expected.

Any ideas where I made a mistake?

Thanks for the help upfront!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to use an absolute path on 'somefile.php'. It is probably getting created in the pwd of cron. Or you could do a chdir at the beginning of the script of in the cron statement.

Comment: Thanks Swish!

The problem was the paths to the files. Using the absolute paths help in my case.

Thanks again!